# sessions in "Add to cart" php - Webcart

Tags: php, arrays, session, multidimensional-array, 2d

```
session_start();
        $aaa=$_REQUEST['bb'];

        $_SESSION['bookrec']=array(
        'book1'=>array('callno'=>123005,'price'=>number_format(1380,2),'desc'=>'Attack on Titan Anthology','auth'=>'Scott Synder'),
        'book2'=>array('callno'=>123006,'price'=>number_format(844,2),'desc'=>'Binge','auth'=>'Tyler Oakley'),
        'book3'=>array('callno'=>123004,'price'=>number_format(598,2),'desc'=>'A Work in Progress','auth'=>'Connor Franta'),
        'book4'=>array('callno'=>123003,'price'=>number_format(668,2),'desc'=>'The Amazing Book is Not on Fire','auth'=>'Dan Howell, Phil Lester'),
        'book5'=>array('callno'=>123002,'price'=>number_format(760,2),'desc'=>'Children of Eden: A Novel','auth'=>'Joey Graceffa'),
        'book6'=>array('callno'=>123008,'price'=>number_format(799,2),'desc'=>'Username : Evie','auth'=>'Joe Sugg'),
        'book7'=>array('callno'=>123009,'price'=>number_format(440,2),'desc'=>'The Maze Runner','auth'=>'James Dashner'),
        'book8'=>array('callno'=>123007,'price'=>number_format(572,2),'desc'=>'Anne Frank: The Biography','auth'=>'Melissa Muller'),
        'book9'=>array('callno'=>123001,'price'=>number_format(699,2),'desc'=>'This Book Loves You','auth'=>'Pewdiepie')
        );
        $selected=array();

        if($aaa=='book1') {$_SESSION['b']=implode("<td>",$_SESSION['bookrec']['book1']);}
        if($aaa=='book2') {$_SESSION['b']=implode("<td>",$_SESSION['bookrec']['book2']);}
        if($aaa=='book3') {$_SESSION['b']=implode("<td>",$_SESSION['bookrec']['book3']);}
        if($aaa=='book4') {$_SESSION['b']=implode("<td>",$_SESSION['bookrec']['book4']);}
        if($aaa=='book5') {$_SESSION['b']=implode("<td>",$_SESSION['bookrec']['book5']);}
        if($aaa=='book6') {$_SESSION['b']=implode("<td>",$_SESSION['bookrec']['book6']);}
        if($aaa=='book7') {$_SESSION['b']=implode("<td>",$_SESSION['bookrec']['book7']);}
        if($aaa=='book8') {$_SESSION['b']=implode("<td>",$_SESSION['bookrec']['book8']);}
        if($aaa=='book9') {$_SESSION['b']=implode("<td>",$_SESSION['bookrec']['book19']);}

        if($aaa=='book1') {$_SESSION['bo']=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book1']['price'];}
        if($aaa=='book2') {$_SESSION['bo']=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book2']['price'];}
        if($aaa=='book3') {$_SESSION['bo']=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book3']['price'];}
        if($aaa=='book4') {$_SESSION['bo']=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book4']['price'];}
        if($aaa=='book5') {$_SESSION['bo']=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book5']['price'];}
        if($aaa=='book6') {$_SESSION['bo']=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book6']['price'];}
        if($aaa=='book7') {$_SESSION['bo']=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book7']['price'];}
        if($aaa=='book8') {$_SESSION['bo']=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book8']['price'];}
        if($aaa=='book9') {$_SESSION['bo']=$_SESSION['bookrec']['book9']['price'];}

                    foreach($_SESSION['bookrec'] as $data){
                        if($data == $_SESSION['bookrec']['book1']) {
                            $selected[]=$_SESSION['bo']; 
                            echo "<table class='w3-table w3-khaki'><tr><td>&nbsp".$_SESSION['b']."</td></tr></table>";
                        }
                    }   
                echo "<center><b>TOTAL AMOUNT:</b> Php ".number_format(array_sum($selected),2)."</center>";

        ?>
```

I have a problem on this code... When I add the item into the cart, it retains the item to the cart but there's an error saying

```
Notice: Undefined index: bb in C:\xampp\htdocs\Webcart_ch\Webcart\mycart.php on line 85
```

the index 'bb' is on the checkbox, if the checkbox has ticked then it will output the contents. I am really getting there but I dont know what to do! Please help..

Comment: Side note, You should be able to do `$_SESSION['b']=implode("<td>",$_SESSION['bookrec'][$aaa]` and `$_SESSION['bo']=$_SESSION['bookrec'][$aaa]['price'];` instead of all the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a typo 'book19' here:
if($aaa=='book9') {$_SESSION['b']=implode("",$_SESSION['bookrec']['**book19**']);}

Let me know if this fixes it: Change 'book19' to 'book9'

```php
if($aaa=='book9') {$_SESSION['b']=implode("<td>",$_SESSION['bookrec']['book9']);}
```